# Script-.....sh: line 2: npm: command not found Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: react-native

It is one project building error.The other project can be built.
The error message is the title just a simple error message.

Answer (score 1):

Try these solutions, from [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/123790).

**Solution :1**

You can try following these steps,:

1- Delete your Podfile.lock (I like to use the command '-rm -rf Podfile.lock' on the terminal for this)

2- Delete your Pods folder (I like to use the command '-rm -rf Pods' in the terminal for this)

3- Delete your .xcworkspace

4- Pod install

5- Clear your project into XCode> Product> Clean Build Folder

**Solution : 2**

go to VSCode(IDE APP), and ios/App/App.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj that file , and search for
EXCLUDED_ARCHS = arm64; and delete that line